# Sublime Text 2 opens last opened files from last session

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2, default-settings

Whenever I open Sublime Text 2 on Fedora, it used to restore the last session.

But now in Mac OS X Mountain Lion, and it's not opening the window from the last session. What setting do I need to change?

Comment: "hot_exit": true,
"remember_open_files": true

Comment: both of the above values are set to true by default.

Comment: How are you closing Sublime? CMD + Q, File->Quit ect..

Comment: @spuder just going to the windows and clicking on 'x'

Comment: @spuder - that's it. Sublime isn't being closed all the way, just the windows are. See my comment below my answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way that sublime is closed, determines the behavior.

---

Completely closing Sublime with

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>

will cause sublime to cache the open files, and resume them on startup.

---

Closing just the window with

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>

or

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>

or

Clicking the red button close button in the corner

will cause Sublime to prompt to save the file. It will not reopen the last files.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I think that's coz of how the 'x' button beahves in Mac OS X. It actually doesn't close the application.

Comment: This works. But I gotta say, having to close the app in a different way for this to work is horrible.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting

```
"create_window_at_startup": false,
"hot_exit": true, 
"remember_open_files": true
```

in your `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file (accessible from the `Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Preferences - User` menu). If they're there you can ensure that they're being applied. The `hot_exit` and `remember_open_files` settings should already be `true` by default, but `create_window_at_startup` also defaults to `true`, and setting it to `false` should do the trick. Probably what's happening is Sublime is creating the new, empty window on startup, but for some reason is not remembering the previously-opened files. I'd also double-check that your `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages` directory hasn't been modified, deleted, set to read-only, or otherwise corrupted.

Comment: that's not working. :( When I set "create_window_on_startup:false" now it doesn't open any single windows when I start Sublime for the first time. I need to click it twice but still no files from last oepn session.

Comment: If you're closing the windows by just clicking on the red dot in the upper left, you're not really closing Sublime Text - it's still running in the Dock. Try opening a window, and opening several files in it. Then, hit `command-q` to close Sublime **completely**, then click on the Dock icon to open it up again. Your files should all reappear.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior in Mac by going to System Preferences / General and uncheck "Close windows when quitting an app"

Comment: Sorry but apparently this option is not even working in Yosemite!